# Difference between two 'if' statements and an 'if/else' loop

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement

I've listed below a question and two answers. The logic behind the answers seem the same to me, but solution A works while solution B returns 'false' unless 'x' is the first letter of the string. Why is that?

Question:

Write a function called hasX(). It should take as input a string, and it should return true if the string contains the character 'x', and false if it does not.

Solution A:

```
function hasX(s) {

for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
if (s[i] === 'x') {
    return true; 
} if (s[i] !== 'x') {
    return false;
}
}

hasX('I play the xylophone');

// returns true
```

Solution B:

```
function hasX(s) {

for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
if (s[i] === 'x') {
    return true; 
} else {
    return false;
}
}

hasX('I play the xylophone');

// returns false
```

Comment: In this situation there isn't a difference.  Not even the number of cpu cycles.  So in the above I would use Solution B, as it is more clear that it is an if else

Comment: The missing curly braces around the for loop change the behavior to be misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference here is that in your first example, you have *two* `if` statements while in the second, you have *one* `if-else` statement. Since your `for` loop doesn't have any braces, it only contains the *first* statement after it, so properly nested, they're like this:

```
for
    if

if


for
    if-else
```

In the first example, the second `if` would execute *after* the loop was all done, if it finished. In the second example, the entire `if-else` executes on every iteration of the loop.

The first loop iterates until it finds a character with the value `x` or reaches the end of the array, while the second one returns immediately, because the first character is either `x` or it isn't.

In actuality, you don't need two conditions. You can properly write your function like this:

```js
function hasX(s) {

  for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (s[i] === 'x') {
      return true;
    }
  }

  // didn't find an x
  return false;
}

console.log(hasX('I play the xylophone'));

console.log(hasX('I play the piano'));
```

I would advise always using braces around the bodies of your loops and `if` statements. It helps to prevent sneaky bugs like this.

Comment: Thank you! I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

In your case there is logically no difference in between two "if" or "if/else" statement.
This example will tell you the difference in general:
example 1:

```
function name{
if(condition 1){ //Task1; }
if(condition 2){ //Task2; }
}
```

In this example if both conditions are true your code will run through both loops unless the loop is returning a value (which stops the further code from executing).

example 2:

```
function name{
if(condition1){ //Task1; } //loop1
else{ //Task 2; }         //loop2
}
```

In this example the code will run either loop1 (if "condition1" is true) or loop 2(otherwise), so your code if run just through either one of the loops.

Answer (score 0):

**IF-ElseIF:**

```
start;
if() \\true
break;
end;
```

IF = FALSE - go to ELSE-IF. If TRUE - break.

**IF-IF:**

```
start;
if() \\true
if()
end;
```

Execute 2 IF's.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with effeciency and your needs. If statements are executed independant of one another. Each one will run. Else if statement's only execute if the previous if's fail. :)

Answer (score -1):

Both of those functions will return `false`, because they each test the first character and return.

What you want to do is return `true` only if the character is == 'x'. If it is not, you don't want to return yet. You need to allow the loop to proceed and check the next character.

Only after you've checked all the characters and your loop ends will you know that the string has no 'x', so only then should you return false.